# Turn a div into a link

Tags: html, css

I googled how to turn a div into a link but there seem to be a lot of techniques, none of which seem like they would work well in IE.

What is the best/simplest technique for turning a div into a link?

Comment: How about using a _link_ in the first place?

Comment: Instead of turning a DIV into a link, why not turn a link into a block-level element? `A.block { display: block; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an anchor tag and display it as a block element?

```
a { 
   display: block; 
   //remaining code here
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but this seems like it may give me trouble with different browsers - especially IE

Will this technique validate?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "into a link"? You could do this:

```
#mydiv {
  color: #00f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mydiv:hover {
  color: #f0f;
}
```

Comment: I need to create a div that users can click on and go to a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

or do you mean this?

```
<div onClick="window.location = 'http://www.cannonade.net';">blah</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Raw JavaScript:**

```
<div onclick="alert('You clicked me !')">Click Me</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#div_id').click(function(){
  alert('Clicked !!');
});
```

**Or**

```
<div class="myBox">
     blah blah blah.
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});
```

The above code cancels the default action of link (going to link) with `return false` and binds the `click` event to the div with class `myBox`, then it finds the link's `src` attribute inside the div and `window.location` is used to redirect the page to the `src` attribute of the link present inside the div. So this basically makes the div clickable.